# What are <bpy_struct> and how to get their values?

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to store API and their values into a .json. and as i'm browsing through blender API sometimes instead of having the value, We can get a <bpy_struct> object

For example

```
C.object.bl_rna.properties["color"] # or through C.object.bl_rna.properties.items()
```

will get me `<bpy_struct, FloatProperty("color") at 0x00007FF6C4A67210>`

What is this Type?
How is it used? How can I get it's value instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Property definitions saved in blender rna.**

When we define a prop with `bpy.props` the methods are akin to python's `property` method, extended to save the details in the blend files `rna`.  (From the geneticists mumbo jumbo)

All the things we define in the definition funcion, in this case `FloatVectorProperty` are stored here.  The value when set is stored as a custom property in the file.

Even tho we don't need to define `Object.color` it's very, very similar to  as if we defined

```
>>> from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty
>>> bpy.types.Object.xcolor = FloatVectorProperty(
...         size=4,
...         default=(1, 1, 1, 1),
...         )

>>> C.object.bl_rna.properties['xcolor']
<bpy_struct, FloatProperty("xcolor") at 0x7fa4ee68d288>
```

Which looks just like

```
>>> C.object.bl_rna.properties["color"]
<bpy_struct, FloatProperty("color") at 0xc110c20>
```

Instance value

```
>>> C.object.color
bpy.data.objects['Cube.004'].color

>>> C.object.color[:]
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

Some defaults.

```
>>> C.object.bl_rna.properties["color"].default
0.0

>>> C.object.bl_rna.properties["color"].array_length
4
```

The array's default value

```
>>> C.object.bl_rna.properties['color'].default_array
<bpy_float[4], FloatProperty.default_array>

>>> C.object.bl_rna.properties['color'].default_array[:]
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```